# How to create an `expl3` package?

Tags: package-writing

By a `expl3` package I mean a package that includes some commands that uses `expl3`. The point is that I want a document to be able to `\usepackage{}` that package and avoid the need of `\usepackage{expl3}` to use the package commands.

I've tried to use `wrapstuff` source code as reference but did not succeed. Could anyone provide an example consisting of the basic elements that can make a `expl3` package work?

Comment: expl3 is included in LaTeX, so if you use a current tex system you don't need \usepackage{expl3}. Apart from this: "did not succeed" is not a sensible problem description. Show what you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: If "*avoid the need of \usepackage{expl3} to use the package commands*" meant, that the user should not need to use `expl3`, then just also define user commands in standard LaTeX syntax for the user interface. So, e.g., if you habe a `\mypackage_foo:n` that should also be a user command, define something like `\newcommand{\MPfoo}[1]{\mypackage_foo:n {#1}}` in your package.

Comment: @cabohah But inside the .sty file should the LaTeX3 code be written normally?

Comment: To be able to use LaTeX3 code, you have to switch on expl3 syntax either using `\ProvideExplPackage` or `\ExplSyntaxOn`. See [the `l3kernel` manuals](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are *many* `expl3` packages you could use as references: I would strongly suggest my [`notes2bib`](https://github.com/josephwright/notes2bib) as a model for a small packages, and [`siunitx`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx) as a model for a larger one.

All that is needed within package code is for `expl3` syntax to be active. That is easily done using

```latex
\ProvidesExplPackage {<name>} {<date>} {<version>} {<desc.>}
```

which does the same as `\ProvidesPackage` but also switches `\ExplSyntaxOn`. The LaTeX kernel will automatically turn `\ExplSyntaxOff` at the end of the package code, so we do not need to worry about that.

Comment: What's ```{<desc.>}``` for？

Comment: @youthdoo It's the description of the package, which appears in the `\listfiles` output and is classically given in `\ProvidesPackage`. For example, for `siunitx` that part reads `{A comprehensive (SI) units package}`.